# Can't set managed bean property

Tags: ibm-sbt

When I try to set a tokenstore property to my managed bean, I will get an error
[image]

In my faces-config.xml I put my tokenstore Managed Bean and I refer to this managed bean in my Endpoint managed bean. I follow the example in the SDK Install guide on page 20.
[image]

What do I do wrong? Or is the SDK Install guide not up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a bean called memoryStore defined as well?  For example here is the Smart Cloud Store..

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>SmartcloudStore</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.store.MemoryTokenStore</managed-bean-class>

    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<value>#{memoryStore}</value>
```